# read encoding excel file in python 3

Tags: python-3.x

Hi there I want help with this :

```
xlsfile = 'D:\\example.cvs'
txtfile = 'D:\\A2.txt'


v= codecs.open(txtfile, 'r','utf-8').read()
v=word_tokenize(v)
    #v = f.read().split('\n')

new_v = list(v)
#wb = codecs.openpyxl.load_workbook(xlsfile,'r', encoding="utf-8")

wb = open('D:\\AA.csv','r', encoding='utf-8').read()
reader=csv.reader(wb)
#ws = wb.active
for cells in reader.rows:
    val = cells[0].value
    if val in v:
        index = v.index(val)
        new_v[index] = cells[1].value

f=codecs.open(txtfile, 'w','utf-8')
f.write(' '.join(new_v))
```

**I got Error:**

```
 for cells in reader.rows:
 AttributeError: '_csv.reader' object has no attribute 'rows'
```

Comment: I want help -> [God helps those who help themselves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_helps_those_who_help_themselves). In other words, try to understand the problem by yourself, explain what you've understood, and ask about what you don't understand.

Comment: I understand but i have question if have answer that is ok if not can you please let other share answer

Comment: I don't think you understand. First, I am not preventing the other to answer with a comment. Second, my comment means that you need to improve your question in order to get answers. In its current state, it's just a "debug my code plz" question, which is not acceptable.

Comment: ok, thank you very much, my question how can i compare the token in (v) with the first column in (wb )  if they in this column then replace these token with the value in second column  and if they not in the fand save the change in (v). and if they not in first column then leave it as it is